# Excel VBA Concatenate to include Time Zone

Tags: vba, excel

Since getting Time Zone in VBA is just too complicated and I only need to add "PST" text string at the end of the function `Now()` so it would look something like **12:30 PM PST**

Just time only and so far I have...

`Range("a1).Value = Format(Time, "HH:MM am/pm" PST)`

which is not right :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Range("a1").Value = Format(Time, "HH:MM am/pm") & " PST"
```

It is possible to include PST in the format string, but I'd prefer to keep it separate personally:

```
Range("a1").Value = Format(Time, "HH:MM am/pm P\ST")
```

The escaping of S with \S is required, otherwise it inserts the seconds.

Comment: This is it! I had problem with that inserting seconds to the date.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
    Range("A1").Value = Format(Time, "HH:MM am/pm") & " PST"
```